# HTML formular JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html

I have a problem with JavaScript. When I push the "Add" button I want to create a table with the listings from the form.

So for example:
New course: name: A, content: B => Add

```
|name|content
|  A |   B
```

And every new record comes to the end of the table.
Do you have an idea how can I do this? With PHP I would be easy but I want to do it with JavaScript.

My idea is to add this code into script:
document . addEventListener( 'DOMContentLoaded', registerCallbacks ); function registerCallbacks( ) { var addButton = document.getElementById( 'add‘ ); addButton.addEventListener( 'click', function( evt ){ add( ); evt.preventDefault( ); } );

```js
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', registerCallbacks);

function registerCallbacks() {
  var addButton = document.getElementById('add‘ );   addButton.addEventListener( '
      click ', function( evt ){ add( ); evt.preventDefault( ); } );
```

```html
   <html>
    <body>
    
    <form id="new">
    <label for="name">Name of lecture: <br>
    <input class="text" type="text" id="name"></input><br> 
    <label for="content">Content: <br>
    <textarea class="text" id="content"></textarea><br> 
    <button id="add"> Add </button>
    </form>
        
        
    <script>
    
    </script>
    </body>
    
    </html>
```

Comment: document . addEventListener( 'DOMContentLoaded', registerCallbacks );
function registerCallbacks( ) {
var addButton = document.getElementById( 'add‘ );
addButton.addEventListener( 'click', function( evt ){ add( ); evt.preventDefault( ); } );

Comment: Is `addVL` what is supposed to add data to the table? Do you have anything written for that? If so, editing your question and adding it would be helpful to anyone who wants to try and answer. Do you already have a table defined in the HTML or do you want to generate that only after someone has pressed add for the first time?

Comment: @Marc, be aware that your `Add` button is inside a form, when you click this button it's possible that the form gets posted, refreshing the page after adding each row.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So step one is to activate the button:

```
// Here we call the function Add() if someone clicks the button.
<button id="add" onclick="Add()"> Add </button>
```

Now we want to add the Javascript function Add() to our script:

```
function Add() {
    // We request here all the information what the user fill out.
}
```

So here is a working snippet:

```js
let table = document.getElementById("table");

function Add() {
  // We request here all the information what the user fill out.
  let name = document.getElementById("name").value,
      content = document.getElementById("content").value;
      
  // Add to table
  table.innerHTML += "<tr><td>" + name + "</td><td>" + content + "</td></tr>"
}
```

```css
table {
    font-family: arial, sans-serif;
    border-collapse: collapse;
    width: 100%;
}

td, th {
    border: 1px solid #dddddd;
    text-align: left;
    padding: 3px;
}

tr:nth-child(even) {
    background-color: #dddddd;
}
```

```html
<label for="name">Name of lecture: <br>
<input class="text" type="text" id="name"><br> 
<label for="content">Content: <br>
<textarea class="text" id="content"></textarea><br> 
<button id="add" onclick="Add()"> Add </button>

<table id="table">
  <tr>
    <th>Lecture</th>
    <th>Content</th>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 1):

Hope this will work

```js
 

 $(document).ready(function() {
  $("#add").click(function(){
    var name=document.getElementById("name").value;
    var content=document.getElementById("content").value;
     $("#table").find('tbody').append("<tr><td class='column'>"+name+"</td><td class='column'>"+content+"</td></tr>");  
  });
});
```

```html
<html>
<head>
<title>Add New Row</title>
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<style>
.head {
  border: 1px solid ;
  background:#AEB6BF;
}
.column {
  border: 1px solid ;
  background:#EAEDED;
  
}
</style>

</head>
<body>


<label for="name">Name of lecture: <br>
<input class="text" type="text" id="name"></input><br> 
<label for="content">Content: <br>
<textarea class="text" id="content"></textarea><br> 
<button id="add"> Add </button>

  <table id="table" class="head">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <td>Name</td>
                <td>Content</td>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
        </tbody>
</table>
<script>

</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a way to achieve it:

```js
var add_button = document.getElementById("add");
var name_field = document.getElementById("name");
var content_field = document.getElementById("content");
var table = document.getElementById("table");

add_button.addEventListener("click", function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  table.style = "display: block;";
  table.innerHTML += "<tr><td>" + name_field.value + "</td><td>" + content_field.value + "</td></tr>"
});
```

```html
<head>
  <title>HTML Formular Table</title>
</head>

<body>

  <form id="new">
    <label for="name">Name of lecture: <br>
    <input class="text" type="text" id="name"></input><br> 
    <label for="content">Content: <br>
    <textarea class="text" id="content"></textarea><br> 
    <button id="add"> Add </button>
    </form>
    <table id="table" style= "display: none;">
            <tr>
              <th>Name</th>
              <th>Content</th>
            </tr>
    </table>
```